# Js: Загрузка картинок в окно

Tags: javascript

мне необходимо нажимая на ссылку, создавать программно окно в которое должна загружаться картинка, на другую ссылку ещё картинка и того уже 2 картинки. У меня 3 ссылки соответственно максимум может быть 3 картинки. + в конце должна быть кнопка закончить, которая закрывает окно.
У меня картинки загружаются, но  одного типа и неопределённо много раз так же как и кнопка. Как это можно исправить?
P.S. Извините, что так туплю, совсем новичок в этом

```js
function OpenWin() {

  var link_1 = document.getElementById('link_1');
  link_1.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var newWindow = window.open("", "newWindow", "location = no"),
        element = newWindow.document.createElement('button');
      element.innerHTML = 'Закончить', element.id = 'but', element.onclick = function() {
        newWindow.close()
      };

      var img_1 = newWindow.document.write('<img 
        src = "images/1.jpeg" > '); 
        // newWindow.document.body.appendChild(element);

      });

    var link_2 = document.getElementById('link_2'); link_2.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var newWindow = window.open("", "newWindow", "location = no"),
        element = newWindow.document.createElement('button');
      element.innerHTML = 'Закончить', element.id = 'but', element.onclick = function() {
        newWindow.close()
      };
      var img_2 = newWindow.document.write('<img src="images/2.jpeg">');

    });


    var link_3 = document.getElementById('link_3'); link_3.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var newWindow = window.open("", "newWindow", "location = no"),
        element = newWindow.document.createElement('button');
      element.innerHTML = 'Закончить', element.id = 'but', element.onclick = function() {
        newWindow.close()
      };
      var img_3 = newWindow.document.write('<img src="images/3.jpg">');
      newWindow.document.body.appendChild(element);

    });


    console.log(img_1, img_2, img_3);

  }
```

```css
body {
  background: #4169E1;
}

a {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="OpenWin()" id="link_1">Экзюпери</a>
<a href="#" onclick="OpenWin()" id="link_2">Маленький принц</a>
<a href="#" onclick="OpenWin()" id="link_3">Лис</a>
```